# How is a web server expected to behave when overloaded?

Tags: http, web, webserver

I'm interested in the correct behavior (standards-wise or otherwise best practices) when a web server is under heavy load: should it return error codes, refuse connections, timeout, something else?

Comment: According the official registry of HTTP status codes, [503 Service Unavailable](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.4) indicates that indicates that "the server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload or scheduled maintenance."

Comment: "According to", double "indicates that", shame on me twice.

Comment: @approxiblue : make that an answer and the bounty is yours :) Bonus points if you can make it slightly more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would definitely be to give the client a clear explanation of why their request could not be processed. Refusing connections or timing out doesn't tell the client what's happening, so they may (wrongly) assume any number of things about the server, for instance that the server has moved, service is gone, server is misconfigured, or really anything that could cause a refused connection or timeout. The 503 error code is there to give a clear indication that service is temporarily disrupted due to overload or maintenance and will be back soon, so if that's your case, then you should definitely return that error code.

**Here's why the other options aren't as good:**

If the server refuses the connection, the client may assume that the service is permanently unavailable, or that they have not properly authenticated (which should really be a 403), but really, a refused connection could mean just about anything. The client doesn't know that the server is overloaded.

If the server times out, again this doesn't really tell anything useful to the client. The client may assume that the server is unreachable and the service is permanently gone from that location, or it may assume that the web server is incorrectly configured. Again, the client doesn't have a clear indication that the server is overloaded, it has to guess.

This means that the best option is sending a 503 error. A 503 error describes exactly why the client is unable to get service right now. It basically means "service is not available at the moment, but it will be soon, so try again". From the [ietf spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4):

> The 503 (Service Unavailable) status code indicates that the server
> is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload
> or scheduled maintenance, which will likely be alleviated after some
> delay.

If that describes your situation, then **tell that to your client** with a 503 error, so the client doesn't have to try to guess what a refused connection or timeout might mean. HTTP status codes are there for a reason, so use them!